# Simple proxy server for development

Tags: proxy, testing, application

For some development purposes I need to use a proxy server with authentication to test applications. I use Squid but sometimes I just need a simple configurable proxy where I need to provide hostname/ip address, username, password and port and run tests.

Is there any lightweight proxy server for development purposes?

Comment: 3Proxy - free tiny cross-platform HTTP/HTTPS, SOCKS proxy server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many proxy servers. I'm not aware of any designed specifically for "development purposes", but I've used [Tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) for many things, including a few development/test deployments. If squid is overkill, then Tinyproxy is probably right for you.